# Looking for iOS music player which includes all id3 information

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, music, id3-tag

I have open-ended tags stored in the Grouping field of my (iTunes) mp3 collection. I also have information written in the Comments field. A lot of my music is also BPM'd. How can I search by/sort by/access these fields in iOS? The Music app and the 3rd party apps I've looked at so far don't provide this.

Comment: Which 3rd party apps have you looked at already (helps to avoid searching/proposing the wrong ones)?

Comment: Oh dear, too many to list. Groove and DJay are my biggest disappointments so far.

Comment: Also looked at Ecoute, Panamp, InstanTunes

Answer (score 1):

[Music Stats](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/music-stats/id384926637?mt=8) provides *some* of what you're looking for, I think. It doesn't show all ID3 tags, but it does provide a few of them.